Snowflake COPY option ESCAPE=NONE does not work
I have many csv.gz files. There is one detail that I could not overcome, my data has single backslash inside of it, and snowflake gets that as escape character. Because of that I pass ESCAPE=NONE or ESCAPE=' \ \ ' but did not work
Example data:

R2\ ,0.0,,,1568

Here is my code:
    COPY INTO TABLE_NAME 
      FROM @stage_name
        FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = CSV, COMPRESSION = GZIP, ESCAPE= NONE,
FIELD_DELIMITER=',',SKIP_HEADER=1,FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"',EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE, NULL_IF=('')),
        PATTERN = 'my_pattern',
        ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE'



ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD=NONE

Solved the problem
